# Crear una ventana modal para implementar textos completos

Tags: javascript, jquery

El problema es que no sé cómo crear un modal donde le asigne el texto de un `div` y mostrar más del mismo, pero tomando en cuenta de que `div` quieres  ver la información.

Éste es mi código:

```css
#container{
  width: 100%;
  background: tan;
}

.paragraph{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: brown;
  color: white;
}

#boton{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  color: white;
  background: slateblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>Primer párrafo resumido en la presentación (Primer bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Primer bloque)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="basic fixed top right"></div>
  <div id="boton">Ver mas</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>Primer párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="basic fixed top right"></div>
  <div id="boton">Ver mas</div>
  
  <div id="container-fixed">
    <div id="salir">X</div> 
  </div>

</div>
```

Aquí parte de un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego que se le de "Ver más" (o en inglés "*Read More*"), me gustaría que mostrara el resto de su información en un modal fixed usando jQuery. ¿Cómo podría hacerse eso?

**Nueva Imagen del Proyecto**

*Este modal tiene position: fixed, pero el tamaño del contenido sobre pasa el alto de pantalla; en este caso de una pantalla smarthones*

*Como podria solucionar este problema, en donde el contenido de parrafo entre  y se pueda hacer escroll*
El otro detalle es que el body lanza su scroll como se visualiza en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Su HTML **

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún framework/librería para esto (tipo Bootstrap)?

Comment: Y viendo tu código, ¿es `#container-fixed` lo que quieres que sea el modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es que:

1. El modal esté escondido por defecto (con CSS)
2. Cuando se pulse en un botón de "Leer más":

   1. Poner el contenido de ese contenedor en el modal (con JS)
   2. Mostrar el modal (con JS o CSS)
3. Para que el contenido del modal sea todo visible (incluso el texto que es invisible), fuerza su `display` a `block` (con JS o CSS).

Voy a suponer que el modal es el `div` con id `#container-fixed` y lo voy a sacar de donde está y ponerlo fuera de los contenedores de datos, para que sea genérico. Y entonces el código quedaría algo como esto:

```js
// cuando se pulsa un boton
$(".boton").on("click", function(e) {
  // copiamos el código a una variable y lo ponemos en el cuerpo del modal
  var codigo = $(this).closest(".container").find(".paragraph").html();
  $("#contenido-modal").html(codigo);
  // mostramos el modal
  $("#container-fixed").addClass("active");
});

// cuando se pulsa en la X del modal
$("#salir").on("click", function(e) {
  // escondemos el modal
  $("#container-fixed").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background: tan;
}

.paragraph{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: brown;
  color: white;
}

.boton{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  color: white;
  background: slateblue;
  text-align: center;
}

/* CSS del modal: siempre fijo en el centro de la pantalla) */
#container-fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:400px;
  background:#ffff00;
  /* escondido por defecto */
  display:none; 
  /* maximo 80% o muestra scroll */
  max-height:80%;
  overflow:auto;
}

#container-fixed.active {
  display:block; /* lo mostramos si activo */
}

/* forzamos que los p del modal sean visibles con !important */
#contenido-modal p {
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>Primer párrafo resumido en la presentación (Primer bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Primer bloque)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="basic fixed top right"></div>
  <div class="boton">Ver mas</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>Primer párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
    <p style="display: none;">Segundo párrafo resumido en la presentación (Segundo bloque)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="basic fixed top right"></div>
  <div class="boton">Ver mas</div>
</div>


<div id="container-fixed">
  <div id="salir">X</div> 
  <div id="contenido-modal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: amigo y si ese mensaje del modal es mas grande de la pantalla de un telefono como haria ya que el fixed y un posicionamiento fijo; habra una forma de que el modal cubra toda la pantalla pero a su vez dependa de la cantidad de contenido ?

Comment: He rechazado tu edición porque deberías editar tu código en lugar del mío (de ese modo otros usuarios también podrán ver el problema). Lo que quieres es posible con CSS, es cuestión de limitar el alto/ancho del modal y hacer que si excede el tamaño se muestren las barras de scroll.

Comment: ya te muestro en una imagen para ser rapido y consiso al explicarte

Comment: perfecto amigo, muy hermoso tu codigo me facina porque es una manera muy limpia de trabajar eso es lo que hando buscando solo queda un detalle que es este: Que pasa si el texto es muy amplio y no entra en el fixed ???

Comment: @Gamez He modificado el CSS del modal para que si excede un 80% del alto de la ventana se muestren las barras de scroll. Simplemente había que añadir `max-height:80%; overflow:auto;` a los estilos del modal. Si quieres que sea todo el alto de la ventana, cambia el porcentaje a 100%.

Comment: ya lo reviso amigo

Comment: perfecto amigo solo falta un detalle y es que en la pantalla se mantiene 2 scroll, como se haria en este caso ?

Comment: pense en quitar el scroll al body en jquery, cuando el boton se le de el click y asi solo se quedara el scroll del modals, que opinas

Comment: No termino de comprender, pero si es lo que me imagino, tendrías que hacer que cuando se abra el modal el `overflow` del `body` sea `hidden`, y cuando se cierre quitárselo.

Comment: perfecto eso hare, te pasare la imagen solo para que lo veas amigo

Comment: hay esta la imagen como me aparece y ya lo arreglo, gracias amigo por tu ayuda